# Update Label in scrollview with pageIndex

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a scroll view in which i have a label. i have to update the label's text each time the user scrolls the scrollview. i want to update the label's value with pageindex.I am getting the page index in scrollviewdelegate method but unable to update it in label as the label gets loaded in viewDidload. Any way to refresh or update the label's text from scrollview delegate method?

Answer (score 0):

Make the label a property and use the property to set the labels text.

Property (assuming arc enabled project):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *myLabel;
```

ViewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.myLabel = [UILabel new];
}
```

and update your label texts from inside the viewController like this:

```
self.myLabel.text = @"test";
```

Comment: once check your viewDidLoad method

Comment: mh :) indeed a label is not a button :)

Answer (score 0):

take all the values in one array and assign the label text based on the `pageindex` like below

```
label.text=[titlesArray objectAtIndex: pageindex];
```

for achieving this one you can take label globally.

```
EDIT:-
```

for achieving this one you can do two ways.

1.take UILabel in Xib and connect the label with some name and you can set the labelname.text in scrollviewDidEnd method .

2.take uilabel programatically and define that one in .h file and change the textscrollviewDidEnd particular method.

Comment: this will not work as the pageIndex will get added only when i scroll and until i scroll, and the label is getting loaded before all this happens ie. in viewdid load so it will always return null

Comment: you want to change the value of label when you scroll the scrollview from one page to another am i right(if your scrollview paging enabled)?

Comment: once check my Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

HERE **pageNumber** is number which update and get when you scroll  `UIScrollView`

Write this code in where your get **pageNumber**

```
Yourlbl.text = pageNumber;
```